# npm install ember-cli fails on ubuntu trusty in vagrant virtualbox

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I have not been able to successfully install ember-cli. I finally was able to run:

```
sudo npm install -g ember-cli
```

But when running:

```
user@host:~ ember new ember-app
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I installed node.js from the repositories using sudo apt-get install nodejs and same with npm.

I have installed bower and tried to re-install npm. Here is the last error:

```
user@host:~ npm install -g ember-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli/-/ember-cli-0.2.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli/-/ember-cli-0.2.7.tgz
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for /home/user/tmp/npm-14461-xfhNCJKF/1435776262780-0.6301117099355906/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: fefcd9fe7faf276a5a68c8bfcc92288c0f0678d5
npm ERR! Actual:   c120ca4196f11da6e51f9c8ebb273439dcfee615
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/sha/index.js:38:8
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/sha/index.js:85:7)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

For clarity, I am able to install other items using npm. Just not ember-cli.

UPDATE:

I am getting similar errors that I've received in previous executions of npm install -g ember-cli when run the following:

```
npm install -g latest-version
```

Received the following error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--global" "latest-version"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/latest-version'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

-

UPDATE:
"Fix" is in the comment below.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Ember

Comment: So turns out this is not about Ember, but about a permission issues on a Vagrant Box with 2 users. I decided to destroy the box and 'vagrant up' a new one and just use the main (vagrant) user. Problem solved. Well, problem not solved but this is a good enough fix for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

For your node issue, try the following command which will make it so your system recognizes your node.js directory as node:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Regarding the issue with administrator access, simply run your commands with sudo at the beginning. Sudo is usually required in situations where modifications to the filesystem are necessary.